# How does the MQTT works? unable to get the data if the receiver file is started after the sender file

Tags: python, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I'm new in MQTT there is a simple range of numbers which I want to print I have created 2 files in which the 1st file whose send data to the 2nd file and the script is like that:

```
sender.py

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("192.168.1.169", 1883, 60)
for i in range(1,100):
    client.publish("TestTopic", i)
    print(i)
client.disconnect()
```

receiver.py:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    client.subscribe("house/bulbs/bulb1")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    # print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    print("message received ", str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=", msg.topic)
    print("message qos=", msg.qos)
    print("message retain flag=", msg.retain)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("192.168.1.169", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

I'm able to print the data if the receiver file is active but I have a problem in printing it if I started the sender file and then I started the receiver file ,**main question is does MQTT follows the queueing Mechanism or not** if yes then ....if I'm running the sender file then its all data should be in queue and after that when I'm run the other file which is receiver then I should get printed.. but its not working in the same way please help me I went lots of documents but i'm able to find any relevant info.. recently I found **clean_session** if someone have knowledge about this please tell me ....have any questions related my code or anything please let me know 
thanks

Comment: Set the retain flag on the message to keep the last one sent to a topic. And contrary to its name MQTT does not queue as you might know it from AMQP services.

Comment: @KlausD. thnx for the reply but can you please explain me more about it how to do it actually i didn't get it what do you mean by  set retain flag?

Comment: You are printing the retain flag already, so I expected that you are familiar with it. You just have to set `retain=True` on the `publish()`

Comment: @KlausD. thnx for that but i want to get all the data not only the last one is it any way to do it ...now its printing the 99 which is last but i want get from beginning to end please tell me is it possible?

Comment: That publisher code is really nasty. Move the client creation/connection and disconnect to outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

MQTT is a pub/sub protocol, not a message queuing system.

This means under normal circumstances if there is no subscriber running when a message is published then it will not be delivered.

It is possible to get the broker to queue messages for a specific subscriber, but this requires the subscriber to have been connected before the message is published and to have subscribed with a QOS of greater than 0. Then as long as it reconnects with the clean session flag set to false and the same client id after the publish then the broker will deliver the missed messages.

Retained messages are something different. If a message is published with the retained flag set to true then the broker will deliver this single message to every subscriber when they subscribe to the matching topic. There can only ever be 1 retained message for a given topic.

Comment: thnx for the answer but is there something in MQTT which let me to publish data and store somewhere if MQTT subscriber is down. Once the subscriber will be active it will get the data from it. basically want to use MQTT and i don't want any data loss so either a subscriber is active or not ....please let me know that we can implement like that or not ,any help will be appreciated...thanks

Comment: That is what I described in the 3rd paragraph

Comment: yea i got that i have implemented that way but in my code i tried to send the data which is range from 1 to 100 if i use retain=True its only sending 99 as you said the same thing but main motive is to print all the data not only 99 or one data please don't mind but my question was same from beginning i don't want to lose any single data please tell me that still i'm not clear ....thanks

Comment: No, not the paragraph about Retained messages, the one before about high QOS subscriptions and having the broker queue for a previously connected client which is currently offline.